# EE 4.0.4 - Save Templates as Files

Tags: templates

User guide states:

2. Set Template Preferences
   From the Control Panel, go to **Settings** ‣ **Template Settings**.

Set Save Templates as Files to **Yes**.

but there is no such setting on the template settings page

whazup?

Comment: You're right!?!. Even in the Template Manager->Template->Settings i can't find the setting!?.. But my project is 4.0.4 and i work with the saved templates?!.. Maybe because i updated from 4.x.x.

Comment: It's been reported as a "bug" in the doc.  I guess it's now always saving the templates as files?!?

Answer (score 2):

From **EE3**, it becomes smarter. They had **removed** this option to `Save Template as Files`. It is **automatically** saved all the templates as files **by default**. You just need to create any template group and then provide `Short name` in `General Settings`. It will **automatically** create the folder with your `Short name` and inside it you can find the template group and its files. No need to set `Save Template as Files` to `Yes`.